# Setting up a SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster Instance on an Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, azure, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to set up a test lab in Windows Azure for a SQL Server 2012 Standard Failover Cluster.  When deploying a SQL Server 2012 VM through the gallery, the instance that's created is pre-installed as a standalone instance.  From what I understand, there's no way to migrate that into a FCI so I would have to install it that way from scratch.

Is it possible to deploy a SQL Server VM as a Failover Cluster Instance, or even deploying a plain Server 2012 and installing SQL Server from scratch after the fact?  All while staying within the licenseing provided to me through Azure?

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870962.aspx) for setting up SQL Server Always On?

Comment: Well I was under the impression that Always On was only available in Enterprise version.  My organization only has access to SQL Standard 2012

Comment: Yes, that's true. And it wasn't until *just now* that I noticed you called out Standard edition in your question...

Answer (score 2):

When images are instantiated on Azure, the full setup package for SQL Server is made available on the C drive of the VM. I have not tried this out, but it should be possible to launch that setup to install the first instance of the SQL Server with a Failover mode enabled.

Comment: as per this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/05bbfa0f-4ece-4380-aba6-8a052f7048ba/is-it-possible-to-have-a-cluster-disk-from-cloud-storage?forum=windowsazuredata), looks like it is not possible to directly cluster the Azure disks ...

Comment: and this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/f3e38072-53f7-4589-8218-0e921016df7a/is-it-possible-to-have-a-cluster-disk-from-cloud-storage?forum=windowsazuredata)